# PHP: Any function that return first/last N elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want a function that will return last/first N element of an array.

**For example:**

```
$data = array( '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10' );
```

**If**

```
getItems( $data, '5', 'first' );
output: array( '0','1','2','3','4' )
```

**If**

```
getItems( $data, '2', 'last' );
output: array( '9','10' );
```

**if**

```
getItems( $data, '11', 'first' ); or getItems( $data, '11', 'last' );
output: array( '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10' );
```

Is there already a function like this. If not then what is the shortest way.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `array_slice()` (man page [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)).

Example:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$slice1 = array_slice($arr, 2); //take all elements from 3rd on
$slice2 = array_slice($arr, 0, 3); //take first three elements
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getItems($data, $length, $startLocation){
   if($startLocation == 'first'){
      return array_slice($data, 0, $length);
   }else if($startLocation == 'last'){
      $offset = count($data) - $length - 1;
      if($offset < 0) $offset = 0;
      return array_slice($data, $offset, $length);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tested your function. I think 5th line should be `$offset = count($data) - $length;`. Otherwise it does not consider last element of input array.