# php foreach (show only 10 of them)

Tags: php, foreach, include

**I have this code:**

```
<?php
$files = glob("notes/last.*.*/table.php");
rsort($files);
foreach($files as $tables) {include $tables;}
?>
```

**with output:**

```
tables
tables
tables
```

This will include many php's files from starting from last to the older post.

I want to include only the first **10** of the output. (that is the last 10 added)
how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447127/php-any-function-that-return-first-last-n-elements-of-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
$i= 0;
foreach($files as $tables) {
  $i++;
  include $tables;
  if($i == 10) break;
}
```

Comment: Op needs last 10 elements, not first 10.

Comment: i think its ok, hmm, its show the right way, but the top one is not in the right way, am testing it.

Comment: @user2773673 this would only work if you sort your array descending so that the last 10 added would be the first 10 in the array.  Why would you declare a counter variable outside the foreach loop when you could just use a for loop to get the same results?

Comment: @Andrew yes, as you can see i have sort it, i want the last 10 added to be the first 10 in the output, this is that i want.

Comment: @user2773673 I saw that you did the reverse sort on it, but the comments below your code segment said you want to include the last 10.  If you are doing the reverse sort just so that the last 10 will be first, you don't need that and can do what I did in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$limitedArray = array_slice($files, count($files) - 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a reverse sort so that the last 10 entered are the first 10 in the array.  You can get the count of the array, subtract that from 10, and loop to the end of the array.  You will need to change your foreach to a for loop.

This should include the last 10 from the $files array:

```
for ($i = (count($files) - 10); $i < count($files); $i++)
{
    include $files[$i];
}
```

Comment: i test your code and its not working,meaby i have forgot to add something, can give the full code? to test it.

Comment: Can you include your full code for initializing your files array?  What error are you getting?